# Is there an actual use for OpenPGP authentication keys?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, pgp

The OpenPGP specification (RFC 4880) describes, [page 34](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-34), the different capabilities that an OpenPGP key may have; including:

> 0x20 - This key may be used for authentication.

In [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/), one of the most popular implementations of OpenPGP, it is possible to generate [sub]keys with the authenticate capability (using the `--expert` flag). Okay, great, I know have a key which has the four capabilities – Encrypt, Certify, Sign, Authenticate (ECSA). Now what?

I am curious about that Authenticate capability. **Is there any real-world use for authentication OpenPGP [sub]keys**, other than [not using them and export them as SSH keys](https://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable) instead?

Comment: By the way, [GnuPG 2.1 can now export SSH keys](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#sshexport), using `--export-ssh-key`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [informational RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6091) for use of OpenPGP keys in SSL/TLS; as the RFC says:

> ```
> The term "OpenPGP key" is used in this document as in the OpenPGP
> ```

```
specification [RFC4880].  We use the term "OpenPGP certificate" to
refer to OpenPGP keys that are enabled for authentication.
```

That's what these keys are for: usages as part of *authentication* protocols which may technically look like signatures, but are not meant to fulfil "non repudiation" requirements.

I never saw a working implementation of RFC 6091, though. I don't think it gets much used anywhere.